# Trigger a button click when users scrolls to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in Joomla, so it is hard to produce a fiddle, but this is the idea:

I have a mosaic grid of 12 articles being shown on page load, and a 'Load More' button - when clicked, 12 more will load, and so on.

How can I trigger the button to click itself when the users scrolls to it, and automatically load the next 12, and so on?

Button HTML:

```
<div class="loadmore">
<span class="loadmore-text">load more</span>
</div>
```

On Button click:

```
container.addEvent('click:relay([data-mosaic-loadmore])', relay['loadmore']);
            container.addEvent('click:relay([data-mosaic-orderby])',     relay['ordering']);
            container.addEvent('click:relay([data-mosaic-filterby])',     relay['filtering']);
```

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery's trigger events?

Comment: I think that you should first show us the button code, with the function that is triggered when a click occurs to this button. Because technically, if you know the button onclick function, you can call it when the user scroll up to a certain distance in pixels.

Comment: Joomla has nothing to do with it, and you can setup a jsfiddle just as well. Furthermore; what have you tried? And look at this, it'll help you to setup a nice example for us: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Zeratops, thank you for pointing that out, I added the snippet that had any click action - the rest is other code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user scrolled to the end?

Compare $(document).scrollTop with the height of the document and if you´re on the bottom you can trigger a click.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {

            var height = $('body')[0].scrollHeight;
            if (height - $(document).scrollTop() < 1.1 * $(window).height()) {
                loadConent();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting how far you've scrolled down is not a good approach as you may find in the future that the length of your content will change, therefore you will have to update the value.

Instead, I would suggest doing something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var loadmore = $('.loadmore');

    $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        if (loadmore.visible(true)){
            loadmore.trigger('click');
        }
    });

});
```